# Highlight method definitions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

When I look at my code I am needing some time (even though parts of a second) to differenciate between the several method/property definitions. (Sorry for my bad English) It would be nice if method borders would be **more highlighted**.

What I want is

- a seperator between methods or
- a highlighted (e.g. bold) method name or
- somewhat else

that shows me more highlighted where a method ends and where the next method begins.

I searched a related *Display item* in Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors. But did not find the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [VS10x Editor View Enhancer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87):

> **Overview**
>
> VS10x Editor View Enhancer is a Visual Studio 2013/2012/2010 extension
>   whose goal is to add new visual features to the built-in code editor.
>   It currently features type and member definitions emphasizing,
>   end-of-block details, clickable hotspots (C# and VB documents).

Answer (score 3):

I had an interest in the same thing, so I decided to write an extension.  It puts a rounded border around constructors, static methods and methods.  When the signature scrolls off the screen, it puts it vertically up the left hand side of that border.

Yes, methods should be small enough that identifying the start/finish is easy to parse visually "just from the code", but we're not always modifying code we've written and *especially* in the case of poorly written God Objects and methods that do *way too much*, this sort of thing can be very helpful.

I also wanted to be able to easily see the constructor and static methods among the others (people don't always organize their code the same way), so my extension allows separate coloring rules for each along with a few other little tweaks that you can configure in the editor.

I've released it for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 in the extension gallery - [here's the details with links to each](http://matthewdippel.blogspot.com/p/stay-frosty-method-and-constructor.html)

Answer (score 1):

It *should* be obvious where one method ends and another begins. Perhaps the issue is colourscheme and environment settings?

This suggestion falls into your "somewhat else" option - Try [studiostyl.es](http://studiostyl.es/) - there are some good alternatives to the visual settings on there and a change in appearance might be what you really need, rather than tampering with the code itself.

Comment: I have tried quite a few 'dark' themes from the studiostyl.es site but none of them really worked well with the extra colours that Resharper adds (sure I could have configured those manually) but most other windows in Visual studio (and pretty much every other application) uses a white background. I just turn the brightness down on my monitor if the white is too much to look at all the time.

Comment: I have tried to create a new style with studiostyles. The tooltip of the method shows "Identifier" for method names. So there is only one style for all identifiers. After that I changed the *Identifier* item (in Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors) to be bold and then all identifiers are bold. That is not what I want.